# Program adding two elements but it's should add only one. Python

Tags: python, list, pygame

I am making a simple sudoku game but this piece of code should only add one element in the list but it is adding two. Although its not creating any problem but when the list will become more big, I can slows the program performance.

This is the piece of code:

```
def typing(text_cor, pos):
    global numbers, equal
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_1]:
        numbers = 1
    if keys[pygame.K_8]:
        numbers = 8
    if keys[pygame.K_7]:
        numbers = 7
    if keys[pygame.K_6]:
        numbers = 6
    if keys[pygame.K_5]:
        numbers = 5
    if keys[pygame.K_4]:
        numbers = 4
    if keys[pygame.K_3]:
        numbers = 3
    if keys[pygame.K_2]:
        numbers = 2
    if keys[pygame.K_9]:
        numbers = 9
    if numbers in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]:
        if len(text_cor) > 0:
            for j in range(len(text_cor) - 1):
                if (
                    pos[0] + 15 == text_cor[j][1] and pos[1] + 10 == text_cor[j][2]
                ) and text_cor[j][0] != 0:
                    equal = True
                    numbers = 0
                if (
                    pos[0] + 15 == text_cor[j][1] and pos[1] + 10 == text_cor[j][2]
                ) and text_cor[j][0] == 0:
                    equal = True
                    text_cor[j][0] = numbers
                    numbers = 0

            if equal == False and numbers != 0:
                text_cor.append([numbers, pos[0] + 15, pos[1] + 10])
                numbers = 0
                equal = True
            else:
                equal = False
                numbers = 0
        if len(text_cor) == 0:
            text_cor.append([numbers, pos[0] + 15, pos[1] + 10])
            numbers = 0
```

I have try to program it so it don't add any other element of the same x and y cor.

Comment: My first suggestion would be not name the func after `typing` , since that’s a builtin module in Python. If possible try changing the func name.

Comment: sorry, for asking question in such a bad way. i am new in stack overflow

Comment: I can suggest that you use `for event in pygame.event.get():` and then check for `if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:` and then do under the if statement `event.unicode` and then check if you can convert it to an integer and check if that as an integer is in the range you need, that way you will save a few lines of unnecessary code, also why do you need to save coordinates? just have a 2D array of the whole board and calculate the values as an item in that array

Comment: @matiss i can't under stand what you are saying "just have a 2D array of the whole board and calculate the values as an item in that array" i don't know about arrays and where to  use it.

Answer (score 0):

now it working fine.
code:

```
for j in range(-1, len(text_cor)):
            if (
                pos[0] + 15 == text_cor[j][1] and pos[1] + 10 == text_cor[j][2]
            ) and text_cor[j][0] != 0:
                equal = True
                numbers = 0
            if (
                pos[0] + 15 == text_cor[j][1] and pos[1] + 10 == text_cor[j][2]
            ) and text_cor[j][0] == 0:
                equal = True
                text_cor[j][0] = numbers
                numbers = 0
            if (equal == False and j == len(text_cor) - 1) and numbers != 0:
                text_cor.append([numbers, pos[0] + 15, pos[1] + 10])
                equal = False
                numbers = 0
            else:
                equal = False
```